# Why does the tooltip pop up too low and then slides up into correct position?

Tags: jquery, popup, tooltip, qtip

I use qTip (1.0.0 rc3) to create nice tooltips on my site and jQuery (1.6, also tried 1.3.2, which was recommended by qTip). The tips are dynamically loaded. I don't use any show or hide effect. Positioning is 'rightMiddle'. I used Firefox and Chrome on Linux and IE on Windows.

When I load the page and then hover over an element for the first time, qTip fetches the contents for the tooltip from the server. During that slight delay, the tooltip initially appears too low (the top edge aligns with the element). Then, after it has loaded the contents, the tooltip slides up (animated over maybe 200 ms) into the correct position.

This can only be observed if there is a bit of delay in serving the tooltip content. When I develop on my local server, the delay is not big enough. I need to add a sleep(1) into the serving function to see this happening. But on the production system, when the request has to actually go out over the Internet, it's always visible.

Is this a bug in qTip? Or is there some setting I don't know about yet?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Probably some code or a link to your problem would help. But if you look http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/loading# it also happens on their demos so probably a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry -- saw your message on the forums but hadn't had a chance to reply yet.

In any case, this is a known bug in qTip v1.0.  A suggested fix is pinned in the forums, but you'll have to make it yourself and minify/pack since v1.0 is no longer under active development (qTip2 is right around the corner):

http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-how-to-disable-the-fly-by-animation-on-1-0

There are a number of other threads talking about the issue if you want to spend the time searching for them.

Edit: Looks like since you posted this question here, Craig has answered your original post in the forums with the same info :)